# Fundamental vector field given by a Lie group action and anti-homomorphism of lie algebras

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\psi : G\times M\rightarrow M$ be a smooth left action of a lie group $M$. For $A\in Lie(G)$, we define $X_A\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ be the fundamental vector field $X_A(p):=\frac{d}{dt}exp(tA).p|_{t=0}$.  Now my goal is to show that $[X_A,X_B]=-X_{[A,B]}$ , so that we  have an anti-homomorphism of lie algebras, here's what I have done :

$[X_A,X_B](p).f=\frac{d}{dt}(f(\phi_{X_B}^{-\sqrt{t}}\circ \phi_{X_A}^{-\sqrt{t}}\circ \phi_{X_B}^{\sqrt{t}} \circ \phi_{X_A}^{\sqrt{t}}(p)))|_{t=0}$

$=\frac{d}{dt}(f(\exp(-\sqrt{t}B)\exp(-\sqrt{t}A)\exp(\sqrt{t}B)\exp(\sqrt{t}A).p))|_{t=0}$

And

$-X_{[A,B]}(p).f=\frac{d}{dt}f(\exp(-t[A,B]).p)|_{t=0}=\frac{d}{dt}f(\exp(t[B,A]).p)|_{t=0}$
$=\frac{d}{dt}(f(\phi_A^{-\sqrt{t}})\circ \phi_B^{-\sqrt{t}}\circ \phi_A^{\sqrt{t}} \circ \exp(\sqrt{t}B).p))|_{t=0}$
$=\frac{d}{dt}(f(\exp(\sqrt{t}B)\exp(\sqrt{t}A)\exp(-\sqrt{t}B)\exp(-\sqrt{t}A).p))|_{t=0}$

Where I have used the fact $\phi_B^t(p)=p\exp(tB)$. And I used the fact, hope it's true , that $exp(t[B,A])=\phi_A^{-\sqrt{t}}\circ \phi_B^{-\sqrt{t}}\circ \phi_A^{\sqrt{t}} \circ \phi_B^{\sqrt{t}}(e)$

so I must be making some mistake since the signs don't quite add up but I can't quite figure out what it is.

It's also weird because if we consider the right action we will have that $[X_A,X_B]=X_{[A,B]}$, and this using the same methods of using the flows I was able to prove like this :

$\phi_{X_B}^{-\sqrt{t}}\circ \phi_{X_A}^{-\sqrt{t}}\circ \phi_{X_B}^{\sqrt{t}} \circ \phi_{X_A}^{\sqrt{t}}(p)=p.\exp(\sqrt{t}A)\exp(\sqrt{t}B)\exp(-\sqrt{t}A)\exp(-\sqrt{t}B)$

$\exp(t[A,B])=\phi_B^{-\sqrt{t}}\circ \phi_A^{-\sqrt{t}}\circ \phi_B^{\sqrt{t}}\circ \phi_A^{\sqrt{t}}(e)$
$=\exp(\sqrt{t}A)\exp(\sqrt{t}B)\exp(-\sqrt{t}A)\exp(-\sqrt{t}B)$

So I am confused where I could have made a mistake in the previous case but possibly not on this one.

Any help is aprecciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did this “fact” come from?

Comment: Doesn't it come from the left-invariance of the vector field ? Suppose we have an element $p\in G$ when we want to know what $\phi_t^X(p)$ is but since $exp(tX)$ is actually the integral curve of $X$ starting at the identity, we will have that $p.exp(tX)$ will be an integral curve passing starting at $p$ do to left invariance. @TedShifrin

Comment: If this were so, wouldn't your expression for the Lie bracket automatically be $0$?

Comment: What expression, the flow of the lie bracket that I wrote ? I don't think so , but I could be confusing something up.

Comment: I was confusing the expression of the flow with the one of the exponential but now I think thigns make sense but I still don't get the result.

Comment: The more fundamental exercise is that with *left-invariant* vector fields on a Lie group, we have $[X,Y]f= X(Yf)-Y(Xf)$, whereas for *right-invariant* we have the negative. (Define the Lie bracket $[X,Y]$ to be the Lie derivative $\mathscr L_XY$.)